# Duplicate Results Using Views, loosing results using (File) File: Content using Thumbnail image

Tags: database, views

I’ve got a “views” question. I have a view that is using `File Usage: File` under advanced > relationships and `(File) File: Content using Thumbnail image`. In that later relationship, `(File) File: Content using Thumbnail image` , when `require the relationship` is checked, I loose nodes that don’t have thumbnail images, when it’s not checked, I get duplicates (the content type holds a thumbnail and a header image and for some reason it returns a result with the thumbnail and a duplicate result with the header image instead of the thumbnail) - Anyone got any idea how I can get both the ones with the images and without, and not have duplicates?

I tried Other > Use aggregation and Query Settings > Distinct (and pure distinct) and didn’t have any luck either

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't get in the view the field that has the image and display it as thumb("image style"). 
That "Content using Thumbnail image" i guess it load every image with an "preview" from the respective node.